# grails 3.1.4 - google-visualization plugin not working

Tags: grails, plugins

I just followed the instructions on https://github.com/bmuschko/grails-google-visualization/wiki/usage ... However, I now get the following error:

```
org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException: [views/participant/results.gsp:57] Template not found for name [/visualization_javascript] and path [/_visualization_javascript.gsp]
```

I wonder how I could verify that the google-visualization plugin has been installed correctly. Obviously, it finds the corresponding taglib but not the required template, or am I mistaken?

In my view I have simply put the line `<gvisualization:pieCoreChart elementId="piechart" title="My Daily Activities" columns="${columns}" data="${rows}" />`. And in the `head` of the gsp I put `<gvisualization:apiImport/>`.

Would be grateful for ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the [files _visualization_javascript.gsp](https://github.com/bmuschko/grails-google-visualization/blob/master/grails-app/views/_visualization_javascript.gsp) and [_formatter.gsp](https://github.com/bmuschko/grails-google-visualization/blob/master/grails-app/views/_formatter.gsp)
in your views folder, seems like actually they were omitted in the build of the latest plugin.